# What am I missing when using PROGMEM?

Tags: c++, arduino, progmem

So I'm trying to store a multi-dimensional CHAR array in program memory on my Arduino and I'm having problems getting it to work.  Here's what I have...

```
typedef unsigned char RGBBitmap[8][8][3];
typedef prog_uchar ProgRGBBitmap[8][8][3]; // Have to use prog_uchar for stuff stored in progmem

ProgRGBBitmap Mailbox[3] PROGMEM = 
{
    ... // some initializing data
};
```

Per the PROGMEM documentation, to get a pointer back to the char data, you should use the pgm_read_word call.  However, when I try to read it back out using this...

```
RGBBitmap * pMailbox0 = (RGBBitmap*)pgm_read_word( &Mailbox[0] );
```

...all I get back is garbage.

If I drop the PROGMEM line and only work with RGBBitmap pointers and drop the pgm_read_word, it works, but then its in RAM, which I'm out of.

So what am I missing here?

Comment: A big question of the day:  What compiler and platform are you using?  None of the compilers I'm using have a `PROGMEM` keyword and I writing for embedded systems and PCs.

Comment: @ThomasMatthews http://arduino.cc/en/Reference/PROGMEM

Comment: Arduino, as called out by the keyword.  Still, I'll update the q to answer that.

Comment: Really you should use `pgm_read_ptr`, not `pgm_read_word`. On AVR a pointer will always be the same size as a word, but if your code is ported to another platform then the difference might become important.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your arrays are a block of values.  Like this your code is defining a continuous block of values:

```
ProgRGBBitmap Mailbox[3] PROGMEM = {...};
... removing typedef is same as ...
prog_uchar Mailbox[3][8][8][3] = {...};
```

So you cannot read a **pointer** from program memory because they are not stored there.  The block is all uchar's.

All your values are bytes, so you would read any value out of that block with:

```
uc = (uchar)pgm_read_byte( someaddress );
```

Now the tricky part for a 4 dimensional array is getting the address syntax correct.

```
uc = (uchar)pgm_read_byte( &Mailbox[i][x][y][c] );
```

The compiler will insert pointer arithmetic for the [i]...[c], which may be wasteful in a loop.  So you can precalculate part of the pointer, which is I think what you where trying to accomplish.  Something like this will save some code and clock ticks:

```
ProgRGBBitmap* ptrOneBox = &(Mailbox[i]);  // this will be pointer into block
for(x ...
  for(y ....
    uc = (uchar)pgm_read_byte( &(ptrOneBox[x][y][c]) ); // this indexes out one byte
```

Pointer and arrays can make you crazy when it doesn't work.  Throw in PROGMEM on a platform with no debugger...

Strip down the problem to a simpler case and work back up.

Comment: Close, but not quite.  Ultimately the multi-dimensions are just a convenience for me when looking at the data and debugging. As you know, they are all stored contiguous in memory so it can actually be treated as a simple char array which can be accessed via a char pointer and pointer arithmetic.  The mailbox was just to advance to a particular 'group' of 192 chars (3 colors in an 8x8 array).  But I get the rest of what you're saying. My mistake was thinking pgm_read_xxx was just converting one pointer in program space into a pointer you can use in RAM space.

Comment: What I don't get is why I have to copy out the chars one at a time instead of simply passing a pointer that I can advance through to get to the others. Your For x/y (and Z) adds 192 single-byte reads instead of just starting at the starting pointer and advancing through it.  That's why I was also trying memcpy_PF or whatever, but that doesn't seem to be defined on Arduino.  To start over (and I hate comments can't have paragraph breaks) I have three blocks of 192 chars that I want to copy all at once to another location in RAM. How can that be done?

Comment: Those are two great questions - but these are comments.  Hints: 1. Harvard vs Von Neumann 2. memcpy_P(dest, (PGM_VOID_P)saddr, n) is available (search for pgmspace.html and pgmspace.h under your Arduino IDE install)

Comment: So to be clear, you can't access the memory in program space directly, you have to first copy it to RAM? Is that correct?